# HTTP Header with Apache HTTPComponents

Tags: java, httprequest, httpresponse, apache-httpcomponents

i writing a basic http Server with a client chat application. I use my own implementation of a HTTP-Server, because i want to understand the functionality.

The Client use the HTTPComponents library from Apache.

If i send e Request to my Server, i got a Failure with this Failure Code:

```
org.apache.http.ProtocolException: Invalid header: <html>
at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parseHeaders(AbstractMessageParser.java:232)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:268)
at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:165)
at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:272)
at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:124)
at com.ssjd.client.sockets.SSJDClient.getNachrichten(SSJDClient.java:130)
at com.ssjd.client.sockets.SSJDClient.run(SSJDClient.java:82)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I send the HTTP Header manually with this containing text :

```
                              "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n " 
                              + "Via: HTTP/1.1 localhost\n "
                              + "Server: Apache/1.3\n " +                         
                            "Content-type:       text/plain; 

                              charset=UTF-8\n " + "content-length:"
                              + body.getBytes().length;
```

The Content Length ist the length of the body text, which is a simple HTML document. In my oppinion, the syntax is correctly, but im not really sure.

Here the Client-Worker class:

```
/**
 * @throws IOException
 * @throws UnknownHostException
 * 
 */
 public SSJDClient() throws UnknownHostException, IOException
 {
  socket = new Socket( "localhost", PORT_SERVER );
 }

@Override
public void run()
{
  try
  {
    getNachrichten();
  }
  catch ( IOException | HttpException e )
  {
    LOGGER.log( Level.INFO, "Fehler beim Verarbeiten der Serverantwort",   e );
  }

}

 /**
   * @throws IOException
   * @throws HttpException
   * 
   */
  protected void getNachrichten() throws IOException, HttpException
  {
    HttpProcessor httpproc = HttpProcessorBuilder.create().add( new RequestContent() )
    .add( new RequestTargetHost() ).add( new RequestConnControl() )
    .add( new RequestUserAgent( "Mozilla/39" ) ).add( new RequestExpectContinue() ).build();

HttpRequestExecutor httpexecutor = new HttpRequestExecutor(
    HttpRequestExecutor.DEFAULT_WAIT_FOR_CONTINUE );

HttpCoreContext coreContext = HttpCoreContext.create();
HttpHost host = new HttpHost( "localhost", RequiredNetworkInformationInterface.PORT_SERVER );
coreContext.setTargetHost( host );

DefaultBHttpClientConnection conn = new DefaultBHttpClientConnection( 8 * 1024 );
ConnectionReuseStrategy connStrategy = DefaultConnectionReuseStrategy.INSTANCE;

try
{
  // Hier ist die eigentliche Anfrage die zum Server geschickt wird.
  HttpEntity requestBodie = new StringEntity( "This is the first test request",
      ContentType.create( "text/plain", Consts.UTF_8 ) );

  if ( !conn.isOpen() )
  {
    Socket httpSocket = new Socket( host.getHostName(), host.getPort() );
    conn.bind( httpSocket );
  }
  BasicHttpEntityEnclosingRequest request = new BasicHttpEntityEnclosingRequest( "POST", "" );
  //wird auf die Anfrage gesetzt
  request.setEntity( requestBodie );
  LOGGER.log( Level.INFO, ">> Request URI: " + request.getRequestLine().getUri() );

  httpexecutor.preProcess( request, httpproc, coreContext );
  //Anfrage wird abgeschickt und es wird auf Antwort gewartet
  HttpResponse response = httpexecutor.execute( request, conn, coreContext );
  httpexecutor.postProcess( response, httpproc, coreContext );

  LOGGER.log( Level.INFO, "<< Anfragestatus: " + response.getStatusLine() );
  LOGGER.log(
      Level.INFO,
      "Body der Anfrage: "
          + (EntityUtils.toString( response.getEntity() ) != "" ? "Leer" : EntityUtils
              .toString( response.getEntity() )) );

  cache.add( getStringFromInputStream( response.getEntity().getContent() ) );

  // umkopieren auf ein Array, damit das wieder angezeigt werden kann
  String[] strings = new String[cache.size()];

  for ( int j = 0; j < cache.size(); j++ )
  {
    strings[ j ] = cache.get( j );
  }

  // in die Liste fügen
  getView().getVerlaufsPanel().getVerlaufListe().setListData( (strings)     );
  getView().getVerlaufsPanel().repaint();

  if ( !connStrategy.keepAlive( response, coreContext ) )
  {
    conn.close();
  }
  else
  {
    LOGGER.log( Level.INFO, "Connection ist geschlossen" );
  }

}
catch ( Exception e )
{
  LOGGER.log( Level.SEVERE, "Fehler beim Senden der Anfrage", e );
}
finally
{
  conn.close();
}
}

// convert InputStream to String
private String getStringFromInputStream( InputStream is )
{

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

String line;
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( is     )   ))
{

  while ( (line = br.readLine()) != null )
  {
    sb.append( line );
  }

}
catch ( IOException e )
{
  e.printStackTrace();
}

return sb.toString();

}

@Override
public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e )
{ 
  switch ( e.getID() )
  {
    case COMMAND_SENDEN:
      LOGGER.log( Level.INFO, "Nachricht wird zum Server gesendet" );
      this.run();
      break;
   } 
  }

 @Override
 protected MainFrame createView()
 {
  return new MainFrame();
 }
}
```

So I hope you can tell me more about those Request/Response Operations and may found a simple solution

Jonas

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you have forgotten to add an empty new line (\r\n) for delimiter between HTTP response headers and body. In this case the client will not know when it has started reading the body.

You can check what exactly your HTTP server returns to client by enabling wire logs on Apache httpclient by adding this parameters to your client's command line:

```
-Dorg.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.log.org.apache.http.wire=DEBUG
-Dorg.apache.commons.logging.Log=org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SimpleLog
```